# Notation: Partial derivative with two indices. What does it stand for?

Tags: notation, partial-derivative, index-notation

I am reading in the book, Gravity from Eric Poisson and Clifford M. Will, and they use a notation of a partial derivative operator with two indices, eg $\partial_{ij}$.

I am sure they must have introduced it somewhere – but I cannot find it.

Is it a standard notation, and if so, what does it mean?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I don't have my copy of the book with me at the moment, but I think I remember that notation just meaning $\partial_{ij} = \partial_i \partial_j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might mean a second derivative with respect to the standard coordinates with those indices, i.e.,
$$\partial_{ij} f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f(x_1, \dots, x_n).$$
Of course, the book might define it in some other way than this, but off the top of my head, this is the only reasonably common usage I can think of.

Comment: It is customary to denote partial derivatives with the symbol $\partial$.  So $$\partial_{ij} f(x_1,\dotsc,x_n) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f(x_1, \dotsc, x_n). $$